# passing parameters between classes

Tags: android, parameters

I'm trying to pass two prameters ( fileURL AND fileNAme) from one class to another one,, but I'm getting errors I got,

```
   04-11 17:19:45.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2958): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    04-11 17:19:45.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2958): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while 
executing doInBackground()
04-11 17:19:45.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2958):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
04-11 17:19:45.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2958):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
04-11 17:19:45.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2958):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
04-11 17:19:45.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2958):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
04-11 17:19:45.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2958):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
04-11 17:19:45.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2958):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
04-11 17:19:45.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2958):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
04-11 17:19:45.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2958):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
04-11 17:19:45.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2958): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
04-11 17:19:45.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2958):     at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
04-11 17:19:45.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2958):     at android.util.Log.e(Log.java:231)
04-11 17:19:45.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2958):     at com.androidhive.androidlistview.pdfDownload$DownloadFileFromURL.doInBackground(pdfDownload.java:155)
04-11 17:19:45.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2958):     at com.androidhive.androidlistview.pdfDownload$DownloadFileFromURL.doInBackground(pdfDownload.java:1)
04-11 17:19:45.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2958):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
04-11 17:19:45.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2958):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
04-11 17:19:45.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2958):     ... 4 more
```

here's

**my first class that pass the parameters to the other class**

```
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new ListView.OnItemClickListener() { 
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
                  int position, long id) { 
                if (position == 0) { 
                    // pass parameters file name & file url 
                    Intent i = new Intent(ListView_SqliteActivity.this,pdfDownload.class); 
                    i.putExtra("FileName","hello.pdf"); 
                    i.putExtra("FileURL","http://www.gradsch.ohio-state.edu/depo/etd_tutorial/lesson2.pdf"); 
                    startActivity(i); 

                  } 

                    else{
                          Toast.makeText(ListView_SqliteActivity.this,
                                    " toast me " + listItemAdapter.getItem(position),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }               }
        });

}
```

**my second class that takes the parameters**

```
public class pdfDownload extends Activity {

// button to show progress dialog
Button btnShowProgress;

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
ImageView my_image;
// Progress dialog type (0 - for Horizontal progress bar)
public static final int progress_bar_type = 0; 
public static String fileURL;

// File url to download
public static String file_url = fileURL;
public static String fileName;



public static String file_name = fileName;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.download);

    // show progress bar button
    btnShowProgress = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnProgressBar);
    // Image view to show image after downloading
    my_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image);
    /**
     * Show Progress bar click event
     * */
    btnShowProgress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            public void onClick(View v) { 
                file_name = getIntent().getStringExtra("fileName");  
                file_url = getIntent().getStringExtra("fileURL"); 
        // starting new Async Task 
        new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(file_url); 

            // starting new Async Task
            new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(file_url);
        }
    });
}
```

after fixing the previous error , a new one comes that is the toast "file not found "message from this class 
`

```
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
            dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);

        }
        File pdfFile = new File("/mnt/sdcard/pass/"+ file_name);{ 
        if(pdfFile.exists()) { 
            Uri path = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile);  
            Intent pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
            pdfIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf"); 
            pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
            try { 
               startActivity(pdfIntent); 
            } catch(ActivityNotFoundException e) { 
               Toast.makeText(pdfDownload.this, "No Application available to view pdf", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
            } 
        } else { 
            Toast.makeText(pdfDownload.this, "File not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
        } 
    }`
```

with new error messages

```
    04-11 18:06:40.809: E/AndroidRuntime(12884): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application android.app.Application: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-11 18:06:40.809: E/AndroidRuntime(12884):    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:482)
04-11 18:06:40.809: E/AndroidRuntime(12884):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3938)
04-11 18:06:40.809: E/AndroidRuntime(12884):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:123)
04-11 18:06:40.809: E/AndroidRuntime(12884):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1185)
04-11 18:06:40.809: E/AndroidRuntime(12884):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-11 18:06:40.809: E/AndroidRuntime(12884):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-11 18:06:40.809: E/AndroidRuntime(12884):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-11 18:06:40.809: E/AndroidRuntime(12884):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-11 18:06:40.809: E/AndroidRuntime(12884):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-11 18:06:40.809: E/AndroidRuntime(12884):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-11 18:06:40.809: E/AndroidRuntime(12884):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-11 18:06:40.809: E/AndroidRuntime(12884): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-11 18:06:40.809: E/AndroidRuntime(12884):    at android.app.LoadedApk.initializeJavaContextClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:362)
04-11 18:06:40.809: E/AndroidRuntime(12884):    at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:305)
04-11 18:06:40.809: E/AndroidRuntime(12884):    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:474)
04-11 18:06:40.809: E/AndroidRuntime(12884):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace of the error from the logcat.

Comment: You have a NullPointerException on the line 155 of your pdfDownload.java file. There is something wrong here.

Comment: here's the line 155  `    } catch (Exception e) {
          Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
         }
         
         return null;
  }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At line 155 in your `DownloadFileFromURL` class you call `Log.e()` with an invalid parameter. Either the tag or the message is null, you can solve the problem by using this code: `Log.e("tag",String.valueOf(errormessage));`

Comment: I have fiexed the previous error by doing what you told me ..ty .. another error is that it is not passing the parameter to this class above by showing me the toast message "file not found"

Comment: @AliDeV: You seem to use keys named "FileName" and "FileURL" in the first Activity, but in the second you have a lowercase f: "fileName" and "fileURL" :)

Comment: you are a great man for seeing this tiny letter lol , u should've named yourself Java  ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use getApplicationContext() instead of ListView_SqliteActivity.this

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),pdfDownload.class);
```